# CEFPython change proxy programmatically

Tags: python-3.x, cefpython

I'm using cefpython for my projects and I would like to change the proxy settings programmatically. The application flow is this:

- application try to connect to internert services, if doesn't works ask to the user for proxy setting
- user insert proxy settings using a local web page in cef
- backend receive this settings and should set the proxy

Last part is missing. I've read about a requestContext object that should provide this functionality but I've inspect object without find it.
Need an example to understand how to proceed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can set proxy only at program initialization using switches passed to cef.Initialize. To change it during runtime cefpython will have to implement Chromium preferences. This is to be done in Issue #244:

https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/issues/244